# React Router onLeave for PrivateRoute

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I am trying to implement the `onLeave` hook from React Router.  When applying it directly to the `<Route />` component it works.

However, when trying to apply it to a higher-order component (HOC) that blocks private routes on the application, I run into typescript issues.

> Type '{ children: Element; exact: true; path: string; onLeave: any; }'
>   is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RouteProps & {
>   children?: ReactNode; }'.   Property 'onLeave' does not exist on type
>   'IntrinsicAttributes & RouteProps & { children?: ReactNode;
>   }'.ts(2322)

The routes are wrapped as follows:

`<ProtectedRoute>`

```
import { Redirect, Route, RouteProps, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
const { component: Component, ...rest } = props;
return <Route {...rest} component={Component} />;
```

Which is then rendered within a layout file:

`<LayoutApp>`

```
import { RouteProps } from 'react-router-dom';

const LayoutApp: React.FC<RouteProps> = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <ProtectedRoute {...rest}>
                <div>{children}</div>
            </ProtectedRoute>
        </>
     );
 }
```

And finally, this is used to wrap the component within the Route Switch.

```
<LayoutApp exact path={ROUTES.DASHBOARD} onLeave={}>
    <Dashboard />
</LayoutApp>
```

The typescript error is occurring on the `<LayoutApp>` component when trying to add the OnLeave hook.

Comment: What react-router version and plugins do you use? Latest react-router doesn't have `onLeave` out of the box.

Comment: I'm using the following

    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.4",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.3",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",

Comment: Does `onLeave` really do anything when applied to the `Route`? It shouldn't unless you have some third-party module which extends `Route`

Comment: It executes when the route is left, I'm not sure what third party library I have that's enabled it but it seems to work OOTB.  I also have access to `onEnter`

Comment: I've not ever heard of `onEnter` nor `onLeave` and it isn't in the react-router-dom docs at all.

Comment: It's really strange, it does work, on my <Route> component, but it's been documented that it's been deprecated for a while, I think I'll not use it at all and just focus on `React.useEffect`.